# Why does Erlang provide built-in ordering (sorting) of the basic data types?

Tags: sorting, erlang

In Erlang, an ordering of the built-in basic data types has been established:

`number < atom < reference < fun < port < pid < tuple < list < bit string`

This means that sorting a list with a variety of different data types is possible. (`[1, 2, 'foo', 42, {3}, 1]` becomes `[1, 1, 2, 42, {3}, 'foo']`).

However, it seems very counter-intuitive to me to have this behaviour defined: Usually, when dealing with an enumerable that has multiple different types of data, I'd use a custom function so the order is exactly as I want.

I would expect a number not be able to be compared (in order) with i.e. strings. In many other programming languages this indeed is true and will throw an error.

Why does Erlang provide this ordering of the basic data types?

Comment: In all sorting functions in Erlang you can provide your own sorting algorithm if needed (AFAIK).

Answer (score 9):

[Quoting Joe Armstrong](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-May/043851.html) (emphasis mine):

> The original reason was that there should be a defined total order
>   over all terms (**why? - so that we could write generic sorting
>   algorithms that could order *any* terms**).
>
> The actual order was based on the idea of "complexity" an integer is
>   "simpler" than an atom. a tuple is simpler than a list and so on..
>
> There was no real definition of "simpler" it was more or less the size
>   that an object took in memory (by which measure [], should have been
>   smallest, but is not :-).
>
> The actual order is not important - but that a total ordering is well
>   defined is important.
>
> /Joe

Comment: The direct quote seems to be as good as it will get, and I do appreciate it. However I still don't see the benefit of a generic sorting algorithm besides there being a definition for one and thus one less error-case. I guess I'm looking for a real-world scenario where the default generic sorting algorithm is useful.

Comment: Another example where the total order gives a 'convenient way' of expressing something is that `42 < infinity` as `number() < atom()`.

Comment: There are a few cases, the being able to treat the atom infinity as greater than any number is one of them. There is also the case that if you have a binary tree or some other data structure that expects to keep data in an ordered way having a global ordering means that you can have a well defined sort means you can have keys of different types.

I think the real benefit is just having well-defined ordering in all cases